# How to define a release environment to execute an automated Azure DevOps TestPlan from C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, automated-tests

I am trying to execute an automated Azure DevOps TestPlan from C# but I do not find all the documentation to do this.

This is an example of my code:

```
string  organizationName = "...";
string  projectName = "...";
int     planId = ...;
string  definitionName = "...";
int     definitionId = ...;
string  releaseName = "...";

Uri organizationUrl = await VssConnectionHelper.GetOrganizationUrlAsync(organizationName);
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(organizationUrl, new VssClientCredentials());

BuildHttpClient buildClnt = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
Build build = await buildClnt.GetLatestBuildAsync(projectName, definitionName);
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference testPlanRef = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference(planId.ToString());
int[] pointIds = new int[] { 1 };

ReleaseHttpClient releaseClnt = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient>();
ReleaseStartMetadata releaseStartMetadata = new ReleaseStartMetadata()
{
  DefinitionId = definitionId
};
Release release = await releaseClnt.CreateReleaseAsync(releaseStartMetadata, projectName);

RunCreateModel testRunModel = new RunCreateModel(
  name                    : releaseName,
  pointIds                : pointIds,
  plan                    : testPlanRef,
  buildId                 : build.Id,
  isAutomated             : true,
  releaseUri              : release.Url
);

TestManagementHttpClient testMngmnt = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

TestRun testRun = await testMngmnt.CreateTestRunAsync(testRunModel, projectName);
```

When I execute this I receive an exception with the message "Both release id and release environment id must be specified".
I searched the internet how to create and pass to the function the release environment without any luck.

Is there anyone that could please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of launching an automated test programmatically with the following steps:

1. create a TestRun for the TestPlan of the automated test
2. create a Release of the Release Pipeline linked with the TestPlan
3. update the TestRun with the Release Id
4. update the references of the VsTest task in the Release to the TestRun
5. update the state of the Release Environment of the Stage containing the VsTest task to InPRogress

I don't know if it is the correct way but it worked for me.